# Extract clock from Date & Time pref pane?

Tags: preferences, clock

In some older versions of MacOS you could run the clock visible in the Date & Time pref pane standalone (think I read about it at MacOS X Hints back in the days). That was sometimes pretty useful. Is that still possible to achieve somehow?

---

Edit: See here http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071111053947248

Comment: I *think* the clock display (separate from the menu bar [analog and digital])was a feature of macOS at the time, that has since been removed

Comment: @SteveChambers You can still see it in the Time & Date prefpane.

Comment: @SteveChambers see here http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071111053947248

Comment: The linked article also mentioned that the functionality was removed with 10.5. And with Ventura and it's revised Preferences/Settings application it may change again.